# LINQ query returning null for nested objects in Entity DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lazy-loading

I have a database I created using entity code first

In that DB I have a structure similar to the following

---

```
class ClassA
{
  public virtual int ID {get;set}
  public virtual string some_text {get;set}
  public virtual ClassB B {get;set}
  public virtual ClassC C {get;set}
  ...
}

class ClassB
{
  public virtual int ID {get;set}
  public virtual string some_text {get;set}
  public virtual string some_values {get;set}
  ...
}

class ClassC
{
  public virtual int ID {get;set}
  public virtual string some_text {get;set}
  public virtual string some_values {get;set}
  ...
}
....
```

---

Finally I have a context for those objects with all of the interface to query the DB

---

```
public class ClassADb : DBContext, IClassADataSource
{
  public DBSet<ClassA> As {get;set}
  public DBSet<ClassB> Bs {get;set}
  public DBSet<ClassC> Cs {get;set}
  ...
}
```

When I create the DB and explore it I can see that it was created what seems to be correctly:

In the ClassA_Table I see foreign keys for ClassB_ID, ClassC_ID, etc as well as all of the primitive types encapsulated in ClassA (ints, strings, bools, dates, etc)

Also when performing something along the lines of:

```
ClassB MyB = new ClassB();
//some code to initialize B
...
Bs.Add(MyB)

ClassC MyC = new ClassC();
//some code to initialize C
Cs.Add(MyC);

ClassA MyA = new ClassA();

A.B = MyB;
A.C = MyC;
...

db.SaveChanges();
```

### I again explore the DB and see in Table_A a new row with references to those B and C objects (row id's corresponding to those objects in the B_table , C_table)

The Problem I am having is that when I do a select from As container , I can retrieve the A object but the nested B and C objects are null

The primitive types are OK (not empty)

Some fixes I tried

The `virtual` keyword is lazy , so in  the constructor of the class accessing the database i did

```
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

But still when doing something along the lines of

```
A myA = db.As.Find(1);

A.some_text ; // not null
A.B ; //NULL!!!!
A.C ; // NULL
```

What is causing the entity framework not to fetch the A and B object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to explicitly load related entities explicitly using [`Include()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx).

```
db.As.Include("B").Include("C").Where(a => [some condition]);
```

In newer version of the Entity Framework there is also a [wrapper method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236) around this method accepting a lambda expression avoiding the strings.

```
db.As.Include(a => a.B).Include(a => a.C).Where(a => [some condition]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Why couldn't I find this in the documentation??!!! Seems so trivial